# svn diff whitespace/tab changes only

Tags: diff, whitespace

Is there way in svn diff or any other tool(linux based) to **show only whitespace/tabs changes** ?.

Purpose, I dont want those diffs to be checked in. I can put back those lines to same state before check in if a tool could catch those diffs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=`svn status | awk '{ print $2}'`
for file in $FILES
do
    COUNT=`svn diff $file --diff-cmd 'diff' -x '-w' | wc -l`
    if [ $COUNT -le 2 ]
    then
       echo "$file has only whitespace changes"
    fi
done
```

Also, instead of putting lines back to the same state, why not just revert those files?

Comment: Thanks mfisch... Sorry if my question wasn't clear at first place. Your answer is almost correct. I want see if any file has lines which has only whitespaces changes. (not the entire file)..

FILES=`svn status | awk '{ print $2}'`
for file in $FILES
do
    COUNT1=`svn diff $file --diff-cmd 'diff' -x '-w' | wc -l`
    COUNT2=`svn diff $file --diff-cmd 'diff' | wc -l`
    if [ ! $COUNT1 = $COUNT2 ]
    then
       echo "$file has whitespace changes"
    fi
done

Answer (score 2):

A couple improvements for @mfisch's script: only work on files with text modifications, and support filenames with spaces.

```
#!/bin/bash

svn status | grep ^M | sed 's/^........//' |
while read -r file
do
    COUNT=$(svn diff "$file" --diff-cmd 'diff' -x '-w' | wc -l)
    if [ $COUNT -le 2 ]
    then
       echo "$file has only whitespace changes"
       # svn revert "$file"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

[Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) will show those highlighted in a different color depending on the type of file. they do have a Linux version, but I have not used it. It is a great diff tool though.

Comment: Thanks Moose. I'm looking for a tool which can be run from command line.. I want to make script based on that which will say if my touched files has "only white spaces changes" on somelines, so dont commit..